# Why is mySql not recognizing my table field

Tags: mysql

I have the query below which is supposed to output a month number and a percentage value. The result when running the query in the mySql console is this. 
"#1054 - Unknows column 'a.vat_number' in table field list"

I dont post the table definition here, but I can assure that all fields in the query are in the database tables.

```
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.trial_date, '%m') AS Month, (COUNT(DISTINCT(b.vat_number))/ 
COUNT(DISTINCT(a.vat_number)) *100,2)as r1  
FROM table1 b 
WHERE b.trial_type = 'KON' 
AND b.case_type NOT LIKE '%opp%' AND b.case_type NOT LIKE '%tva%' 
AND b.case_type NOT LIKE '%sam%' 
AND YEAR(b.trial_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND b.vat_number IN (SELECT vat_number from class_bankrupt) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(b.trial_date, '%m')) 
UNION 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.trial_date, '%m') AS Month1, 
(COUNT(DISTINCT(b.vat_number))/COUNT(DISTINCT(a.vat_number)) *100,2) as r2 
 FROM table2 a WHERE a.trial_type = 'KON' 
 AND a.case_type NOT LIKE '%opp%' 
 AND a.case_type NOT LIKE '%tva%' and a.case_type not like '%sam%' 
AND YEAR(a.trial_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.trial_date, '%m'))
```

Comment: You have `COUNT(DISTINCT(a.vat_number)` in the first half of the union, which presumably should just be `COUNT(DISTINCT(b.vat_number)`, note that the alias is `b`, not `a`.

Comment: I need to divide b.vat_number with a.vat_number and multiply with 100 to get the percentage

Comment: I believe using OUTER APPLY could fix your problem, but I don't think MySQL supports that.

So alternatively, you could wrap the whole thing into a subquery, and then both COUNT values should be recognized in the parent query.

Comment: `table2 a` doesn't exists in the first half of your union, which is why you get an error there. You may meant a join there, but it is a bit unclear what you are trying to do. If you need help figuring this out, please describe what you want to do, add some sample data, the expected outcome, and your table structure.